# Send request from Webserver to Local server

Tags: node.js, apache, api, server

I have a nodejs webserver running on a vserver (rented by me) and a local Raspberry Pi node server.

I dont want to open any ports for beeing accesable from the webserver.
My problem is that I want to create a web application you can interact with and the rpi should do things when any button is pressed on the webserver.

I thought it would be smart to create a json file on the webserver and my local server would listen on the json file.

Is there any better Idea? 
Thx for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem can be solved using reverse proxy softwares that establishes secure tunnels from a public endpoint such as internet to a locally running network service.

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com) is one of the best that I prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a communication between the raspberry and the webserver you need to open a port on the webserver.
However, you can restrict it to allow connections from the raspberry pi IP address only. Or do the connection via ssh and let the raspberry pi authenticate using its public key.